# Keep pressing a button so that a counter keeps adding by 1 every time

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I was thinking if there was a simple way to keep pressing the same button so that the counter keeps adding by 1 every time. So that if the button is clicked two times it will have a counter total of 2 therefore allowing the second if statement to function.

```
int counter = 0;

if(view.getId()=R.id.Spinbtn){
  counter ++;

  if(counter==2){
     showcalcuation(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you only want to test **counter == 2**, just make sure that counter++ is actually **counter = (counter + 1) % 3**. In this way counter variable value never exceeds 2 and will always remain squeezed between 0 , 1 and 2

Comment: Where is your onClickListener?

Answer (score 1):

First, make this global within your class:

```
int counter = 0;
```

Then implement the button click event:

```
 final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Spinbtn);
          button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(view.getId() == R.id.Spinbtn){
                         if(counter == 2){
                            showcalcuation();
                         }else if(counter < 2){
                            counter += 1;
                         }
                    }
               }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems with your code.

1. You reset the counter on each click, it seems
2. You have a single equals in your if statement, which is not a comparison

You can try this instead

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    implements View.OnClickListener {

        private int counter;

        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (view.getId() == R.id.Spinbtn) { // change to your button id
                counter++;
            } 

            if (counter >= 2) {
               showcalcuation();
            } else {
               // hide calculation? 
            } 
    } 

    ... 
        // in onCreate 
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
```